# Click an element based on a comparison in protractor

Tags: protractor

In my e2e testing using protractor,I am taking data from a file and checking whether that data is present in the UI. If present,then click it.

There are about 10 chapters in the page and my file has 2 chapters(indicated as chapterName).I want to check whether the chapterNames in my file are there in the UI and if so,then click one by one.I am working with the below code,but dont know how to do the looping

How to do that in protractor?

```
element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).filter(function (ele,index) {
                return ele.getText().then(function(text){

                return text === chapterName;

            });
            }).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use closure function to achieve looping inside a promise. look at the below example code.

```
 function clickChapterByName(){
   var chapterNames= ['chapter-1','chapter-2','chapter-3','chapter-4','chapter-5']
   for(i=0;i<chapterNames.length;i++){
       function closure(chapterName) {
           element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).filter(function (ele,index) {
               return ele.getText().then(function(text){
                   return text === chapterName;
               });
           }).click();
       }
       closure(chapterNames[i])
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure that i am correct, but i think you are almost there:

```
element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).filter(element=> {
                return ele.getText().then(text=> text === chapterName);
            });
        }).map(element=> element.click());
```

Result of .filter will be only elements that match condition, so you will get new ArrayElementFinder, and you can iterate thru it with .map()

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to do loop operation.So you  can achieve this by each() method which is available in protractor api.

Code Snippet:

```
element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).
            each(function (ele, index) {//for looping purpose
                   ele.getText().then(function(text){
                                      if(text == inputChapterName){
                                         ele.click();//click chapter is 
                                        }
                                   });
           })
```